# Traverse List Token Ring C#

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to implement a Token Ring in C#.
I have thought of the problem like this: I add the pc numbers in a list (called PcSubList) and the pc Ip in another list (IpSubList).
Now when I enter source Pc 4, for example and destination pc 2, the program works fine, but I enter source pc 1 and then I enter pc destination 5, it gets in an infinite while loop.

This is the code that traverses the list:

```
 public void traverseList()
        {
            int pcSourceNumber = Int32.Parse(source);
            int pcDestinationNumber = Int32.Parse(destination);
            int i = pcSourceNumber;
            int f = pcDestinationNumber - 1;
              while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                for(int j = pcSourceNumber; j < pc.PcSubList.Count; j++) { 
                    Console.WriteLine("PC number {0} ", pc.PcSubList[j]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Source IP: {0} ", pc.IpSubList[j]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Destination IP: {0} ", pc.IpSubList[pcDestinationNumber]);
                }

                if (destination.Equals(pc.PcSubList[i]))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("PC number {0} ", pc.PcSubList[i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("The message is : {0} ", message);
                }

                if (i == pc.PcSubList.Count - 1)
                {
                    i = 0; // if the pc index gets to the final element of the list, start reiterating
                }

                if (destination.Equals(pc.PcSubList[i]) && i != pcSourceNumber)
                {
                    while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                    {
                        if (i != pcSourceNumber)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("PC number {0} ", pc.PcSubList[i]);
                            Console.WriteLine("Source IP: {0} ", pc.IpSubList[i]);
                            Console.WriteLine("Destination IP: {0} ", pc.IpSubList[pcDestinationNumber]);
                        }

                        if (i == pcSourceNumber)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
                            Console.WriteLine("REACHED SOURCE AGAIN. PC : {0} ", pc.PcSubList[i]);
                            Console.WriteLine("Source PC IP : -");
                            Console.WriteLine("Destination PC IP : -");
                            Console.WriteLine("Message : -");
                            message = null;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    i++;

                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Can you please help me ? I simply can't what I am doing wrong or maybe I need another approach?

Thx!

Comment: What does the destination class look like?

Comment: `pc.PcSubList.Count != 0` this could be a reason, what is the type of the PcSubList

Comment: `while (pc.PcSubList.Count != 0)` causes the infinite loop. Try changing it to `if (pc.PcSubList.Count != 0)`

Comment: the condition in the while was    ```while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))``` it was my mistake. But the problem still persists. It is a list of strings

Comment: All your loops are dangerous. For example, this one `while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))` will loop infinitely if there are no cases where `i == pcSourceNumber`

Comment: And how should I change them?

Comment: `foreach` is not working for this concept ? did you tried ?

Comment: i didn't try it as I need a kind of repeating loop.. So If I have pc source number 1 and destination pc number 4 I have to traverse the list from 1 to 4 (here I mark that it arrived at destination) and then I have to continue looping until I get back to source again(pc 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, not perfect though, but it will help you to start with some working code

```
class PC
{

    public List<String> PcSubList = new List<string>();
    public List<String> IpSubList = new List<string>();
}



static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PC pc = new PC();
    pc.IpSubList.Add("1");
    pc.IpSubList.Add("2");
    pc.IpSubList.Add("3");
    pc.IpSubList.Add("4");
    pc.IpSubList.Add("5");
    pc.IpSubList.Add("6");
    pc.IpSubList.Add("7");

    Boolean foundStart = false;
    Boolean foundEnd = false;
    Boolean foundReturn = false;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = 0;
    while (!foundStart || !foundEnd || !foundReturn)
    {

        if (!foundStart) {
            Console.WriteLine("F1 " + pc.IpSubList[i] + " " + i);
            if (pc.IpSubList[i].Equals("3"))
            {
                foundStart = true;
                startIndex = i;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        if (foundStart && !foundEnd) {
            Console.WriteLine("F2 " + pc.IpSubList[i] + " " + i);
            if (pc.IpSubList[i].Equals("6"))
            {
                foundEnd = true;
                endIndex = i + 1;
                j = endIndex;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        if(foundStart && foundEnd && j >= startIndex) {
            j--;
            Console.WriteLine("F3 " + pc.IpSubList[j] + " " + j);
            if (j == startIndex) foundReturn = true;
        }

        if (!foundStart || !foundEnd)
            i++;
        if (i >= pc.IpSubList.Count) break;
    }
}
```

`3` and `6` are fixed start and end hard coded inside the code, you can modify this code and make it work for your purpose

`F1` is the path between `zero` and `start`
`F2` is the path between `start` and `end`
`F3` is the path between `end` and `start`

you can remove the `Console.WriteLine` for `F1` if you don't want see that part

Comment: thank you. I will try to understand the logic and run it and come back with feedback :)